# For LORs being drafted by the recommendee, do the contents need to be different?

Tags: ethics, recommendation-letter, workshop

I'm applying to a 24 week workshop (or short school), and I have two former attendees who are willing to write LORs for me. They are either nominated in the front page of the website, or still actively involves in the organization of the current season. They both tell me that I draft the LOR for them, and then they will edit it and sign it.

One of them say that this is just for using the personal reputation to recommend, so the content is not that much important. If so, then is it fine to have two LORs with similar contents? Logically the answer should be yes, but I'm not sure.

The workshop says that LOR is just optional, but it is required that the recommender is a member of the workshop network (e.g. lecturer, alumni, other members).

I haven't let them known that I also have another one to write a letter for me. Should I tell them about this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to judge whether the advice you got (content doesn't matter much) is accurate or not. If they have a lot of experience with the workshop then it is likely accurate.

Make yourself an outline of what your assets are. From the outline either write two drafts stressing different things from the outline, or rearranging the ideas and paraphrasing differently.

And, yes, if the two know one another then it might be worth sending a mail to both of them pointing this out. While they seem to want to support you, they don't seem to want to put a lot of effort into it. Make it easy on them.